# Prevent OneSignal sending Android Advertising identifier

Tags: android, onesignal

I have received an warning from Google Play:

> Reason for warning: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID
>   policy and section 4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

I have been checking and app should be sending the Android Advertising ID. It has to be a library because I am not doing it.

I use crashlytics and OneSignal and both could be the problem. But I have found in the documentation of OneSignal that the SDK get it:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/handling-personal-data#section-personal-information-sent-as-data-tags

> Some data is automatically collected by the OneSignal SDK. For example, on mobile devices this typically include's the device's advertising id, purchases they have made in your app, the timezone setting of the device, and location data (if your app has location permission).

I am trying to disable the SDK continue collecting the advertising identifier but I don't find how to do it. In addition, the list of collected data is not clear because Advertising identifier does not appear:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-collected-by-the-onesignal-sdk

I would need to know how to configure OneSignal SDK for not collecting anymore the Advertising identifier.

Thanks.

Comment: After speaking with JonF (works on OneSignal), I have known that it is not possible to prevent the collection of this parameter from OneSignal Android SDK. So the unique solution at the moment is to add a privacy policy. I hope in the future this changes, so I keep the answer opened and if one day it is possible, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

Google has started emailing apps that use Advertising Id and do not have a privacy policy to tell them they must add a privacy policy.

You can address this by adding a privacy policy to your Play Store listing and in your app. If you do not already have a privacy policy, there are tools available to create one such as http://www.docracy.com/mobileprivacy (free) or https://www.iubenda.com/en/ ($27/yr)

Comment: Sorry, I don't consider this is a solution for me. I don't want my application use the advertising Identifier. I don't think OneSignal needs it for anything so I prefer to block this behaviour directly from the OneSignal SDK.

Answer (score -1):

After speaking a little bit more with JonF, he spoke with OneSignal developers and they said that it is possible to avoid sending the Advertising ID changing some lines in the SDK:

> Most of the tracking for Android can be removed from registerUserTask
>   in
>   https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/3a4d4353b1d803852e3b9986b828c9b823801ce5/OneSignalSDK/onesignal/src/main/java/com/onesignal/OneSignal.java#L1180-L1182

The problem is that it is not possible to keep the library integrated with gradle, but at least it is a solution.

I have been thinking to implement the change with Reflection but I don't have much time now for it, it could be another way.